# How to add a constraint to an NSTextField's baseline in Interface Builder?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, interface-builder, autolayout

I have 2 labels that are stacked and have a bottom space constraint to their common container. I want to hide the lower label if there's no value for it and move the upper label down to the lower label's position. I can do that easily with an outlet bound to the bottom space constraint for the upper label.

[image]

The problem here is that these labels have different font sizes. So, when I set the same value for the bottom space constraint for the upper label, like I have set for the lower one, the upper label does not end up at the same vertical position.

[image]

I assume this is because these labels have different descenders, due to different fontsizes. It would be easy to solve that if I could set the bottom space constraint not for the frame of the text, but its base line. I'd like to do this in IB, if possible.